# Режет форму на разных ОС (Win7/Win10)&Win8.1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-8, windows-10

Написал небольшое приложение. И на кросс-платформенности споткнулся.
Что имеем:

Win10, разрешение 1366х768

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Win10, разрешение 800х600

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь Win8.1, разрешение 1920х1080
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На Win8 срезает кусок формы, тем самым пропадает кнопка нижняя и боковая, что вообще неприемлемо, да и textbox-ы подрезает немного. 
Платформа .NET 2.0 (нужна именно она, перекомпилить в .NET 4+ не вариант).
На Win7 c разрешением 1920*1080 все норм!
В чем проблема может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил установкой значения `Inherit` для свойства `AutoScaleMode`в формах

Answer (score 3):

Поиграйтесь с параметрами [`Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`AutoScaleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Разные контролы по-разному ведут себя с разными значениями этих параметров - проще всего найти правильную комбинацию экспериментально.

Comment: Вот так поворот. Я поставил себе Вин8 на виртуальную машину через VirtualBox и у меня все ОК с формой (ничего не режет). Но почему у моего юзера Вин8 режет форму?! Скажите, пожалуйста, у вас есть версии?

Comment: @DmitryShulga DPI. Поставьте себе на виртуалке другой размер текста в настройках экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего с DPI и абсолютными координатами всех контролов.
Насколько помню, Winform не умеет скалить форму под разные DPI, из за чего как раз правый нижний угол и может страдать.

В целом, из простых вариантов - явно привязать обрезанные контролы к нижней и правой границе окна, либо дать пользователю растянуть форму, что правда не сильно очевидно будет.

Comment: спасибо, не совсем понял, о какой привязке речь

Comment: [`Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx), как и советовали ниже.